# Injecting my settings in the controller works in debug, but not in release

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am very new to Asp.Net Core, so i'm pretty sure i'm doing something stupid but i can't figure which is the problem. So I have written in my appsetting.json a couple of variable i need to retrieve at run time. Following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) i have written in my Startup in the `ConfigureService`

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<AppConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig"));
```

where `AppConfig`

is the following class

```
public class AppConfig
{
    public bool NeedToCheckSession { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

the constructor of my controller is the following:

```
public MyController(IOptions<AppConfig> config)
{
    this.config = config;
}
```

Now when in Visual Studio i run my api in debug via IIS Express, when i send a request to my controller i can hit the breakpoint inside the constructor and the configuration is set correctly. If then i build in Release my project,execute the webapi.exe and attach to the process with visual studio, i see that when i send the same request, i directly hit the breakpoint inside the method, skipping the one in the constructor, with the consequence that the config variable is not setted. Which is the problem?

I add the call i'm using to check if the `config` variable is correctly set

```
        [Route("start")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage MyMethod([FromBody]UserSessionModel userSession)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage resp;


            MyWorker newSession = new MyWorker (config.Value.ConnectionString)
            {
                SessionFolder = sessionFolder
            };


            if (config.Value.NeedToCheckSession == true)
            {
               // i can't enter inside this if, cause even if in the appsetting.json the value is set to true, config is not passed to the controller
            }
```

adding also the json file

```
{
  "AppConfig": {
    "NeedToCheckSession": "true",
    "ConnectionString": "myconnstring;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**EDIT**

To answer some question:

- No i don't use a parameterless constructor, i have only the one i posted above
- I tried to run the api in release mode directly in VS 2017 hosting it on IIS Express, and still, when i send my post request, the breakpoint is not hit inside the constructor and the `config` variable is not setted. If i run the api in debug it works
- To create the exe i simply build the api in release mode and try to run it from the Release folder inside my project. I also tried to publish the api, but the problem still stay

**EDIT2**

Further investigation, revealed that for some reason, in the following `ConfigureService`

```
   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<AppConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig"));
        services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue>();
        // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "My Web Api", Version = "v1" });
            // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });
    }
```

the following instruction are completely ignored (i.e skipped) while running the api in release.

```
        services.Configure<AppConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig"));
        services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue>();
```

while this doesn't happen in debug

Comment: 1) Where are you setting these config values in development and in production? 2) Assuming you don't have a parameterless constructor, then it is definitely calling this constructor. Otherwise, there'd be no ability to get to the action method, and it would be throwing some sort of exception. The remote debugging may be just auto stepping over it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt i don't know how to answer to your first question. I have my appsettings.json in my project folder and i didn't change anything between Release build and Debug build. The only difference is that for debugging i'm using directly visual studio with IIS Express, and for testing the release, i'm directly launching the .exe file

Comment: @ChrisPratt also yes, i don't have any parameterless constructor, so probably the breakpoint is skipped for some reason that i don't know. The content of the debug folder and the release folder is the same, so i really have no clue why it works in debug mode. May it be something related to the fact that Visual Studio host my api with IIS Express?

Comment: Not sure, but parameterless constructors are a big no-no when you're needing to inject dependencies. The DI container is always going to go after the parameterless version.

Comment: If you run project from VS with Release Mode, will you receive any error? How did you generate the `webapi.exe` and `attach to the VS process`? Share us detail steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @TaoZhou i edited my question with firther details. If you need anything else let me know

Comment: @ChrisPratt as i said, i don't have any parameterless constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that it wasn't a problem strictly related to the code, but i found out that i had to disable the option "Optimize code" in the build tab of my project properties, because that messed up my debugger

Answer (score 1):

Use ConfigurationBuilder:

```
 private static IConfigurationRoot Get(string path, string[] args = null, string environmentName = null)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(path)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .AddCommandLine(args ?? new string[0]);

            if (!environmentName.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) builder = builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true);

            builder = builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

            return builder.Build();
        }
```

and:

```
   var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                    ...

                    .UseConfiguration(AppConfigurations.Get(root, args, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")))
                    .UseEnvironment(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"))
                    .Build();
```

Comment: where should i use this? It's not related to the problem i had, cause i solved it, but i'm curious to see what are the benefit of this

Comment: 1. please write your answer for all of us

Comment: 2. the solution above let you have different config files for different environments depends of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment pariable. Appsettings.json will merge whith specific environment appsettings.Test.json or appsettings.Production.json

Comment: thank you. I will make sure to use this approach. As for the answer i've already posted it, and it wasn't something related to the code, but with the optimization of it done by VS